grey bar on Interstitial Ad Along with App name
I integrate a Admob Ads And when Load a Interestial Ad And When it shows a grey bar along with App name appear at the top of ad
Ad Image
Here is my Theme Code
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Base.Theme.LocationFinder" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>
</resources>

manifest Code
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.LocationFinder"
        tools:targetApi="31">

 </application>

</manifest>

How can i fix it
i use AdTheme But that is not good sometimes when ad is shown a full dark theme on Ad
<activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AdTheme"
            tools:replace="android:theme" />


what do you want to do?

i want to remove gray bar from ad

please share main Screen screenshot of the app, is the app have this grey bar without showing the ad or only it appear when ad is showing.

When Ad is Showing then gray bar appear

This is Due to GoogleConsentManager
I use GoogleConset in My Application Class And Also write its override method OnActivityCreated etc And When I Change its Initilization from onActivityCreated to onActivityStart() So issue Fixed
  override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  //before i initialize here Now I move the code to onActivityStarted
}

override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {
    currentActivity = activity
    val manager = GoogleMobileAdsConsentManager.getInstance(
        applicationContext
    )
    manager.gatherConsent(
        activity
    ) { error ->
        if (error != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, error.toString())

//                Toast.makeText(activity, "Consent given!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
Log.w(TAG, "${error.errorCode}: ${error.message}")
        }

    }

